# Angular Karma Jasmine Error: Illegal state: Could not load the summary for directive

Tags: javascript, angular, karma-runner, karma-jasmine, angular-cli

I'm developing a [github repository](https://github.com/Ismaestro/angular4-example-app) (with angular 7 and angular-cli), and I have some tests with Karma and Jasmine working in the master branch.

Now I'm trying to add lazy loading feature, the thing is, that the tests that before passed, now they do not. It's funny because only the tests from the lazy loading module are failing...

Here is the code and the error:

```
import {async, TestBed} from '@angular/core/testing';
import {APP_BASE_HREF} from '@angular/common';
import {AppModule} from '../../app.module';
import {HeroDetailComponent} from './hero-detail.component';

describe('HeroDetailComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [AppModule
      ],
      providers: [
        {provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/'}
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  it('should create hero detail component', (() => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HeroDetailComponent);
    const component = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  }));
});
```

The error is this:

```
Chrome 58.0.3029 (Mac OS X 10.12.6) HeroDetailComponent should create hero detail component FAILED
    Error: Illegal state: Could not load the summary for directive HeroDetailComponent.
        at syntaxError Users/ismael.ramos.silvan/WebstormProjects/angular4-example-app/~/@angular/compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js:1690:22)
        at CompileMetadataResolver.getDirectiveSummary Users/ismael.ramos.silvan/WebstormProjects/angular4-example-app/~/@angular/compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js:15272:1)
        at JitCompiler.getComponentFactory Users/ismael.ramos.silvan/WebstormProjects/angular4-example-app/~/@angular/compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js:26733:26)
        at TestingCompilerImpl.getComponentFactory Users/ismael.ramos.silvan/WebstormProjects/angular4-example-app/~/@angular/compiler/@angular/compiler/testing.es5.js:484:1)
        at TestBed.createComponent Users/ismael.ramos.silvan/WebstormProjects/angular4-example-app/~/@angular/core/@angular/core/testing.es5.js:874:1)
        at Function.TestBed.createComponent Users/ismael.ramos.silvan/WebstormProjects/angular4-example-app/~/@angular/core/@angular/core/testing.es5.js:652:1)
        at UserContext.it Users/ismael.ramos.silvan/WebstormProjects/angular4-example-app/src/app/heroes/hero-detail/hero-detail.component.spec.ts:18:29)
        at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke Users/ismael.ramos.silvan/WebstormProjects/angular4-example-app/~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:391:1)
        at ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke Users/ismael.ramos.silvan/WebstormProjects/angular4-example-app/~/zone.js/dist/proxy.js:79:1)
        at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke Users/ismael.ramos.silvan/WebstormProjects/angular4-example-app/~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:390:1)
```

You can see the entire project, for more details if you need it.

**UPDATE: added declaration like this:**

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        AppModule
      ],
      declarations: [HeroDetailComponent],
      providers: [
        {provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/'}
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));
```

Now, new errors appears:

```
The pipe 'translate' could not be found ("<h1 class="section-title">{{[ERROR ->]'heroDetail' | translate}}</h1>
    <md-progress-spinner *ngIf="!hero"
                         class="progre"): ng:///DynamicTestModule/HeroDetailComponent.html@0:28
    Can't bind to 'color' since it isn't a known property of 'md-progress-spinner'.
```

And more... it's like all directives and components from angular material, and the pipe translate from ngx-translate/core do not appear to be included...

Comment: You do not need to declare the component to test it, you just need to setup the test bed slightly differently: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/17477#issuecomment-510397690

Comment: Instead of "UPDATED: FINAL SOLUTION", please post a [self answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) so that your question is clearly delineated from the solution and the solution is subject to up/down votes along with all other possible solutions.

Comment: I've added the answer from your question as an [actual answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68745394/542251). If you'd like to do this yourself as prompted please let me know and I will delete my wiki

Answer (score 212, accepted):

You passed `HeroDetailComponent` to `TestBed.createComponent()` without declaring the component first:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [AppModule,
     CommonModule,
     FormsModule,
     SharedModule,
     HeroRoutingModule,
     ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  providers: [
    {provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/'}
  ],
  declarations: [HeroDetailComponent]
}).compileComponents();
```

---

Update for following errors in your test: Added some more imports (just take your HeroModule as a blueprint because that's basically what you want to import and provide).

Comment: If I add that declaration, then more errors appears. I updated the info, you can see it above.

Comment: Well, but that's how you get rid of this error. Following errors might be another problem with your test setup.

Comment: What Error comes next?

Comment: The pipe 'translate' could not be found ("<h1 class="section-title">{{[ERROR ->]'heroDetail' | translate}}</h1>
    <md-progress-spinner *ngIf="!hero"
                         class="progre"): ng:///DynamicTestModule/HeroDetailComponent.html@0:28
    Can't bind to 'color' since it isn't a known property of 'md-progress-spinner'.

Comment: And don't forget, that this is happening because it's a lazy loading module. Because the other tests that I have do not fail...

Comment: Hint: just because you're importing the AppModule (which imports your SharedModule) doesn't mean it's available for your HeroDetailComponent in your test. So you should provide any modules / services etc in the Testbed configuration which are used by the component you test. i will update my answer.

Comment: @Ismaestro update my answer. could be that there will be new errors, just let me know and we'll probably get through it step by step..

Comment: Your edited solution will work but i'm used to not import original modules (which i do my tests on, not the dependencies) but provide it manually because you will run into problems soonish when you have to use mocked parts of dependencies. but that's another story.

Comment: You do not need to declare the component to test it, you just need to setup the test bed slightly differently: github.com/angular/angular/issues/17477#issuecomment-510397690

Comment: I forget this everytime and come back to this thread always I have not done any TestHostComponents for a while :D

Comment: "just take your HeroModule as a blueprint because that's basically what you want to import and provide" ... or just import the module itself

Answer (score 12):

You're missing the declarations, you need to add the class being tested into the declarations.

```
declarations: [component]
```

Comment: In my case, I copied TestBed's configuration from one component to the new one and, then, I didn't include the component under test.

Answer (score 3):

My coworker and I had this issue but the fix was way different than anything else on the internet.

We are using Visual Studio Code and the folder names are case insensitive. Because of that, we asked everyone to use a lowercase naming convention but eventually an uppercase name got into source control. We renamed it, in a roundabout way, and everything was fine.

A month later, my coworker started getting a specific unit test to break with this error message. Only his computer was breaking on that test. We literally commented out all the code that could possible be effecting the test and we still got the error. Finally, I globally searched for the class and we realized that the folder name had reverted back to the uppercase name. We renamed it back to a lowercase name, with no pending changes recognized might I add..., and the test worked.

Let that be a lesson to follow style guides. :)

For clarity, the fix was similar to changing the folder name `FOO` to `foo`.

Answer (score 2):

This type of error raised due to missing adding component in declarations and services in provider of TestBed configuration.

```
beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([
        { path: 'home', component: DummyComponent },
        { path: 'patients/find', component: DummyComponent }
      ])],
      declarations: [RoutingComponent, DummyComponent,BreadcrumbComponent],
      providers : [BreadCrumbService]
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

you must import the component ***HeroDetailComponent*** in the right way. **Notice** that even case of letters is matter in paths. i.e ('@angular/forms' is correct, **BUT**'@angular/Forms' is not.

Answer (score 1):

For those who are still having issues with this - I read a separate github issue that discussed changes the Angular team made to the beforeEach callback function.

Here is what I did:

```
beforeAll(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [BannerNotificationComponent]
    }).compileComponents()

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(BannerNotificationComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
}));
```

Using beforeAll fixes the issue. Hope this helps others as it took me about a day to get this resolve this obscure bug.

Comment: For my case, using `beforeAll` actually created the issue.

Answer (score 1):

*Answer copied out of question*

The problem was that HeroesModule was not been imported anywhere. **This works, because HeroesModule declares HeroDetailComponent, which was the initial problem**:

```
import {async, TestBed} from '@angular/core/testing';
import {APP_BASE_HREF} from '@angular/common';
import {AppModule} from '../../app.module';
import {HeroDetailComponent} from './hero-detail.component';
import {HeroesModule} from '../heroes.module';

describe('HeroDetailComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        AppModule,
        HeroesModule
      ],
      providers: [
        {provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/'}
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  it('should create hero detail component', (() => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HeroDetailComponent);
    const component = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  }));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test a component without compiling it then you can by declaring it as a provider:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    // provide the component-under-test and dependent service
    providers: [
      WelcomeComponent,
      { provide: UserService, useClass: MockUserService }
    ]
  });
  // inject both the component and the dependent service.
  comp = TestBed.get(WelcomeComponent);
  userService = TestBed.get(UserService);
});
```

See: https://angular.io/guide/testing#component-test-basics

Answer (score 0):

I imported the wrong module into the test suite! correcting which module was imported fixed this error.