# Angular testing: "Illegal state: Could not load the summary for directive" for an empty component

Tags: angular, angular-cli, karma-jasmine

None of my components were passing unit tests, so I made a new one in the project to try and diagnose.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-thing',
  templateUrl: './thing.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./thing.component.scss']
})
export class ThingComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

And a `thing.component.spec.ts` file as follows

```
describe('ThingComponent', () => {
  let component: ThingComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ThingComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ ThingComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ThingComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

The test fails with
`Error: Illegal state: Could not load the summary for directive ThingComponent.`
I have turned off all other tests with `xit`, so this is the only one running.

I have tried to move in everything (providers, imports, etc) from my `app.module.ts` into the file, which still provides the same result.

When I remove the TestBed configuration, and just have a

```
const comp = new ThingComponent();
expect(comp).toBeTruthy();
```

this passes. However, that's not a long term solution for actual components.

Versions of things:

```
"@angular/cli": "^1.7.2",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0",
"@angular/language-service": "^5.2.0",
"@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
"@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2
"jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
"karma": "~1.7.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
"karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
"karma-jasmine": "^1.1.1",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
...
"@angular/animations": "^5.2.0",
"@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
"@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
"@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
"@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
"@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
```

Any help at all would be appreciated, thanks

**Update**
I even changed the test to `expect(true).toBeTruthy()` and it still gets the same error. I've changed nothing else in the code that was provided by `ng g component`.

Additionally, I made a new angular project in a separate directory, and the tests pass on this new blank project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it. I had a pipe which had a `spec.ts` file as follows:

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [SafeHtmlPipe],
    providers: [DomSanitizer]
  })
  .compileComponents();
}));

describe('SafeHtmlPipe', () => {
  let pipe;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [DomSanitizer]
    });
  });

  beforeEach(inject([DomSanitizer], p => {
    pipe = p;
  }));

  xit('create an instance', () => {
    expect(pipe).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Note how the test is turned off with `xit`. Despite this, and despite that the component under test was not using this pipe, and despite that I imported/declared it in the component anyway, this was causing the issue.

I don't remember writing this, so maybe it was automatically generated, as the pipe it is testing has a `DomSanitizer` in the constructor.

Removing the file did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your test to:

```
it('should create', () => {
    fixture.detectChanges();

    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but still doesn't work with this sadly. I even changed the test to `expect(true).toBeTruthy()` and still gets the same error, which means there's something wrong with the TestBed code maybe? Which is confusing as i've changed nothing from the code provided by `ng g component`. I also made a new angular project in a separate directory, and the tests pass on this new blank project.